# Is it possible to run (execute) an r script from inside of an r script?

Tags: r, shiny

first time here and maybe I am out of place with this question, but I was unable to found an answer

I want to run a Shiny App with only one button, that runs an R script in order to generate a PPT file, something like what happens in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/ZIag8igQtrc/J9PQHi7NjD8J), just instead of the MSWord output the PPT.

I want to avoid to have all the lines inside the ReporteRs-PPT_v3.R script inside the Shiny script and just call it or execute it like in any other lenguage.

I was trying something like this:

```
    observe({
       source("C:/Data/Example/Shiny/App-Ficha/ReporteRs-PPT_v3.R")
    })
```

Also tried this other option:

```
    observe({
       R CMD BATCH /ReporteRs-PPT_v3.R
    })
```

Where ***ReporteRs-PPT_v3.R*** is an existent script that by itself generates a PPT file using **ReporteRs**

Any idea on where can I keep looking?

Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**

The error when try the first option:

```
    Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6158
Error in source(serverR, local = new.env(parent = globalenv()), keep.source = TRUE) : 
  C:\Data\Example\Shiny\App-Ficha/server.R:219:0: unexpected end of input
217:   }
218: )
    ^
```

The error with the second option:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6158
Error in source(serverR, local = new.env(parent = globalenv()), keep.source = TRUE) : 
  C:\Data\Example\Shiny\App-Ficha/server.R:161:9: unexpected symbol
160:       #source("C:/Data/Example/Shiny/App-Ficha/ReporteRs-PPT_v3.R")
161:       R CMD
             ^
```

Also, when I click the button in the Shiny App, nothing happens.

Comment: So, did you get an error message? How do you know it didn't work. Did you have any Shiny specific code in there? Was just no output created?

Comment: Well, the unexpected end of input error sounds like there is an error in the syntax of the file (missing parenthesis or quote or brace) and the "R CMD" way just will never work. That's meant to be done at the command line, not within R. It's likely your script file is just wrong.